# how to reuse android alertdialog

Tags: android, this, android-alertdialog, code-reuse

I want to reuse the code for alertDialog and put it in another java file as function call . But "this" cannot be used  to replace the  "MyActivity.this"? How to pass it as a parameter? Best if the code is generic.

```
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: It's a context, you can send a context to reuse it: new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create()

Comment: Why I cannot use getapplicationContext() as that will be more generic than to use MyActivity.this which will have to be changed in every java/project file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this in a separate class, for example I have used `AlertUtils.java`:

```
public class AlertUtils
{
    public static void showOKDialog(Context context, String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

In this method, the `Context` you pass through could be your Activity's this, eg: `MyActivity.this` or a fragment's `getContext()`

`AlertUtils.showOKDialog(MyActivity.this, "title of dialog", "message to display in dialog");`

Comment: Why I cannot use getapplicationContext() as that will be more generic than to use MyActivity.this which will have to be changed in every java/project file

Comment: This is a more acceptable solution except that I have to refactor the activity name altogether. The code is generic enough.

Comment: There's a good explanation of the different types of context and what they can provide, here: [Context Compatibilities](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)
Scroll down to the Context Compatibilities section near half way down.
 
Basically, the `applicationContext` does not have the ability to display dialogs. The Activity Context is the only context that can show a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Utils {
    public void showDialog(Context context) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

In your `Activity`, you can reuse show dialog by

`new Utils().showDialog(MyActivity.this);`

Comment: Its not a good idea to initialize a class just for a util. Just make your showDialog as `static`.

Comment: @Enzokie Can you explains why? or can you give me some helpful link about it

Comment: [Thus, you should avoid creating object instances you don't need to](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html), Second if you can make your showDIalog as static; you can just plainly do like this `Utils.showDialog(....)` and its way cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your alert dialog code seperately in a class as below :

```
public class Utils{
  public static void showMessage(final Activity activity, String title, String posText){

    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
            .content(title)
            .positiveText(posText)
            .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .build();
    dialog.show();

}
}
```

And from your activity / fragment you can call this as :

Activity,

```
AppUtils.showMessage(this, getString("your text"), getString("your text"));
```

Fragment,

```
AppUtils.showMessage(getActivity(),getString("your text"), getString("your text"));
```

Import Utils class in both fragment or activity then everything will work perfectly.

Hope this helps you to get rid of your problem.

Comment: Can you test run the code? passing "this" from the activity will have an error

Comment: @DriveCarefully I am using this same code in my app .. it is working fine.If it is giving you problem you can try 'youractivity.this' instead of this.

Comment: Since the codes contain other items such as  MaterialDialog so I cannot do some test on it. But it seems we can pass Activity activity instead of Context context. Is there any difference?