# Android: Reuse AlertBuilder instance

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created in a method and i call this method just once, before using this dialog:

```
 private void makeAlertDialogBuilder() {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()),
                R.layout.revisited_dialog, null, false);
        alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).setView(binding.getRoot())
                .setView(binding.getRoot());
        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> alertDialog.dismiss());
    }
```

I have a menu in toolbar so i want wen i click on Add menu item, this dialog opened and shows with new message and when i clicked on edit menu item shows dialog with new message:

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.add_row) {
        alertDialog = alertBuilder
                .setMessage("Add")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();

        exGridAdapter = new RevisitGridAdapter(gridAdapter, baseClass, Action.ADD);
        initRecyclerView(exGridAdapter);
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.edit_row) {
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            alertDialog = alertBuilder
                    .setMessage("Edit")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            exGridAdapter = new RevisitGridAdapter(gridAdapter, baseClass, Action.EDIT, selectedItem);
            initRecyclerView(exGridAdapter);
        }
```

for first clicked, dialog is shown but when it was dismissed and clicked again i got ANR error :

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I have created a one object from `alertBuilder` and i want to use it ? Is it possible or i have to recreate new alertBuilder object?

Comment: this error from `RecyclerView` I think.

Comment: I guess this will help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194234/how-to-reuse-android-alertdialog)

Comment: I got error in this section  `alertDialog = alertBuilder.setMessage("Edit")` when i clicke twice on edit menu item @AbhayKoradiya

Comment: you need to dismiss first. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by removing view from parent and attach to it again in this method:

```
public void showAlerDialogResult(String title) {

    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) binding.getRoot().getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(binding.getRoot());
    }
    try {
        makeAlertDialogBuilder();
    } catch (InflateException e) {
        Logger.log(e.getMessage());
    }
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setView(binding.getRoot());
    alertDialog = alertBuilder
            .setTitle(title)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .show();
}
```

I mentioned `makeAlertDialogBuilder();` method in my question.
I hope it can be helpful.Thanks guys to help me

Tank's to  `ChandraShekhar Kaushik`

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;  // Your Global Object

    AlertDialog.Builder getAlertDialogObject() {
        if (alertDialog != null) {
            return alertDialog;
        } else {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginIssueScreen.this);
        }
        return alertDialog;
    }
```

You need to create a common method for AlertDialog :-

```
    public void showAlerDialogResult(String msg, String title) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = getAlertDialogObject();
            alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
            alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_green);
            alertDialog.setTitle(title);
            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                // Your code on click on ok

            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
             // Your code on click on Cancel

        });
            alertDialog.show();

        }
```

and call it like below -:

```
showAlerDialogResult("Add Button clicked", "Click Event");

                or

showAlerDialogResult("Edit Button clicked", "Click Event");
```

Comment: I do not want every time AlertDialog.Builder recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in a separate class, for example I have used AlertUtils.java:

```
 public class AlertUtils
{
   public static void showOKDialog(Context context, String title, String message)
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
    builder.show();
    }
}
```

In this method, the Context you pass through could be your Activity's this, eg: MyActivity.this or a fragment's getContext()

AlertUtils.showOKDialog(MyActivity.this, "title of dialog", "message to display in dialog");

Answer (score 0):

This issue occur due to open same dialog again without close previous.

You need to check first dialog is open then close it. like,

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.add_row) {
        if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
        alertDialog = alertBuilder
                .setMessage("Add")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();

        exGridAdapter = new RevisitGridAdapter(gridAdapter, baseClass, Action.ADD);
        initRecyclerView(exGridAdapter);
        return true;

    } else if (id == R.id.edit_row) {
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            if (alertDialog != null && alertDialog.isShowing()) {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
            alertDialog = alertBuilder
                    .setMessage("Edit")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
            exGridAdapter = new RevisitGridAdapter(gridAdapter, baseClass, Action.EDIT, selectedItem);
            initRecyclerView(exGridAdapter);
        }
```

Comment: I got error same error again ` alertDialog = alertBuilder
                            .setMessage("ٍEdit")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .show();` @AbhayKoradiya

Comment: I dismissed dialog in `makeAlertDialogBuilder()` method before @AbhayKoradiya